# Weird Copy Paste Behavior

Tags: front-end, cells, clipboard

Since 11 I've been seeing this weird copying and pasting behavior for cell groups. Here's an example where I copied and pasted a cell group below:

[image]

Is there any way to change this back to the usual behavior (so I don't paste with InputForm with the In[] and Out[]'s)?

This is the pasted cell:

```
Cell[BoxData[{
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{"In", "[", "118", "]"}], ":=", 
   RowBox[{"1", "+", "1"}]}], "\n"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"Out", "[", "118", "]"}], "=", "2"}]}], "Input"]
```

Comment: What is the "style" of the new cell?

Comment: @Alan "Input", I added it above.

Comment: What's your `$Version`?

Comment: Latest MacOS, Version 11.0.1

Comment: On Windows 7 x64 I don't see this with versions 11.0.1 and 11.1.0 but you can try `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 "ExportTypesetOptions" -> {"PageWidth" -> 90, "IncludeCellLabels" -> False}];
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "ExportMultipleCellsOptions" -> {"IncludeCellLabels" -> False}]`.